# Cannot call method in red5 server from AS3 Flash CS6

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, remoting, red5

Okay, this had been making me very mad. I've followed almost 8 tutorials all over the Internet and in the end, I got my Red5 server instance working. Good for me! But when I'm calling my Java methods in my Red5 apps from my AS3 apps, in the 'Console' window in Eclipse, I got this error :

```
[ERROR] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.service.ServiceInvoker - Method getTheName with parameters [] not found in org.red5.core.Application@17e5fde
```

Here's my Application.java file.

```
package org.red5.core;

import org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter;
import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.IScope;
import org.red5.server.api.service.ServiceUtils;

/**
 * Sample application that uses the client manager.
 * 
 * @author The Red5 Project (red5@osflash.org)
 */
public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter {

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public boolean connect(IConnection conn, IScope scope, Object[] params) {
        return true;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void disconnect(IConnection conn, IScope scope) {
        super.disconnect(conn, scope);
    }

    public String getTheName() { return "MyName!"; }
}
```

And here's my AS3 code. I just put this on the Timeline.

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect("http://localhost/Mintium/RoomHere", "SomeUsernameHere");
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
nc.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF0;

function onNetStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    switch (e.info.code)
    {
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success" :
            trace("connected");
                              nc.call("getTheName", new Responder(getName_result, getName_error));  
            break;
    }
}

function getName_result(res:Object):void { append("Name : " + res.toString()); }
function getName_error(res:Object):void { append(res.toString()); }
```

Its been a week I've been trying to figure it out and my dateline is next month. If this stuff is not solved, I'm gonna fail my assessment. Please help me with my problems. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure, but why you are using AMF0 as object-encoding. Red5 also supports AMF3, the encoding you should prefer when working with ActionScript 3. AMF0 object-encoding is more outdated and should be used only for older stuff in ActionScript 1.0 and 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I did not see this 2 months ago, I could have helped you pass your assessment. Nevertheless, I think I can answer this question, having had a similar problem calling Red5 services.

The key to solving this problem is in those parts of Red5 that utilize the Spring Framework. In your project, there should be a file called red5-web.xml that resides in the Server project's WEB-INF folder. This file contains some Bean dependencies used by Red5's Spring components. This is not mentioned in the tutorials that I read, or even in most of the (rather sparse and distributed) red5 programming documentation.

What you have to do is add a bean entry for your method in that file. In your case, the entry should look like this:

```
<bean id="getTheName.service" class="org.red5.core.Application" />
```

Note my use of the name of your function, with ".service" appended. I do not understand why, but you need the ".service" appended in order for Red5 to find your function. You need to add a similar entry for every class whose functions you want to use as services.

Of course, I based everything I said above on the fact that you put the service into the Application class -- something which I never do. if you read the red5-web.xml file, you will see that there is already an entry for that class, because it is already injected through Spring as the class that acts as an "endpoint" for processing requests over the web. I do not know if using the Application class as an endpoint and a provider of services is a good idea (it violates "separation of concerns" in OOP and may cause problems with Spring).

What I usually do is add a separate class in the org.red5.core package (or any other package you might want) that acts to deliver the desired service, then put an entry into red5-web.xml that injects the class and its method. So, for your project, lets assume you have a class called NameProvider in the org.red5.core package:

```
public class NameProvider
{
   public NameProvider() {}
   public String getTheName() { return("MyName!"); }
}
```

then you add the following entry to your red5-web.xml file:

```
<bean id="getTheName.service" class="org.red5.core.NameProvider" />
```

That should make everything work.

I hope this helps you in the future, or anyone else having this problem. I just wish I'd seen this question sooner.